# Return teams that have never played each other - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, match, matching

I have the table matches

| id_match | id_team1 | id_team2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | JPN |
| 2 | AUS | USA |
| 3 | CAN | POL |
| 4 | POL | USA |

and the table teams

| id_team | name |
| --- | --- |
| USA | United States |
| JPN | Japan |
| ... | ... |

And i want to return a new table of teams that have never played each other like this

| id_team1 | id_team2 |
| --- | --- |
| USA | AUS |
| CAN | USA |
| ... | ... |

I think i have to use cross join and a subtraction but i can't think exactly how to do it.
if anyone can think of how to do it, or a simpler way, i'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cross join the teams table with itself to generate all possible combinations of matches, then exclude those that already happened with `not exists`:

If you want both team1/team2 and team2/team1 games, then:

```
select t1.id_team id_team1, t2.id_team id_team2
from teams t1
inner join teams t2 on t1.id_team != t2.id_team
where not exists (
    select 1 from matches m where m.id_team1 = t1.id_team and m.id_team2 = t2.id_team2
)
```

If you want a single match between each pair of teams, then we need to add some conditional logic:

```
select t1.id_team id_team1, t2.id_team id_team2
from teams t1
inner join teams t2 on t1.id_team < t2.id_team
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from matches m 
    where t1.id_team = least(m.id_team1, m.id_team2)
      and t2.id_team = greatest(m.id_team1, m.id_team2)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!
i forgot to say, and its important, that only want the combination to appear once

Comment: @Aguss: yes; the second query does that